# I do not get APCu installed with PHP 7.2 on my Mac

Tags: php, apache, php-7, apc, apcu

I changed my default apache server setup on my mac to be able of easily switching between php versions following [this guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions).

Now, when I return to my project which is based on the CMS TYPO3, I get the error, that "The PHP extension "apcu" must be installed and loaded in order to use the APCu backend.".

So I was following [the tutorial (by the same author)](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-mysql-vhost-apc) to install and enable apcu.
I can sum up the installation process:

```
$ sphp 5.6
$ brew install autoconf
$ pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
$ pecl install apcu-4.0.11
```

This actually worked perfectly for php 5.6! But I wanted php 7.2 for my project. The tutorial instructs to do this:

```
$ sphp 7.2
$ pecl uninstall -r apcu
$ pecl install apcu
```

No errors here. But the CMS still claims no apcu! Searching for "apc" in phpinfo also returns in no results! Pecl added the `extension="apcu.so"` line in the loaded php 7.2 ini, so I don't understand what's wrong. Of course I restarted apache every time. Also no errors or warnings here.

Also after googling I have no idea what to do :/

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and can't figure this out :/

Comment: Did you check the apache error_log from startup? Does phpinfo show the so is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using an absolute path of the apcu.so in php.ini,
Like

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2/pecl/20180731/apcu.so"
```

The path depends. Don't know why but this works for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to check the following ini config entry for apcu:

```
apc.enabled=on
apc.enable_cli=on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MUMP - try to check settings.
It helped me.

MAMP -> PHP -> Cache module to speed up execution: -> APC

[image]